# Android: Passing a large image from url to ImageView

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview, bitmapfactory

Right so, I'm creating an Android application where I need to display images from certain URL's. Unfortunately the images are way too large and when I just pass it into a drawable without any decoding it gives me an Out of Memory exception.

Because of this I tried to decode the image first using BitmapFactory.decodeStream.

Here's some code:

First the methods that I use to decode the image:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, String src,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        InputStream input = null;
        InputStream input2 = null;

        Rect paddingRect = new Rect(-1, -1, -1, -1);

        try {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            input = connection.getInputStream();
            //input2 = connection.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, paddingRect, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

       try {
        input.reset();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, paddingRect, options);
    }

public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 40;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

And then where I call on that method in the OnCreate of the activity:

```
imageFrame1.setImageBitmap(
                decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), src, 100, 100));
```

As the code is now, it catches an IOException when I attempt to reset the input stream after decoding it the first time, and then I get the LogCat message: SKImageDecoder::Factory Returned Null.

If I remove the input.reset(); from the code then I get the same LogCat message, just no IOException.

Kinda stumped at this point, hoping someone here has some suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reset a stream from an HTTP connection because the underlying logic is not caching (enough) of the stream.

Create an approach where you write the picture to local storage (disc or memory), then analyze it. Optionally do both at the same time (takes more effort).

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you, but if I try to download the picture without decoding it to be a smaller size then I get a Out of Memory exception due to the huge size of the images.

Comment: Store it on disc and decode it from disc. And by disc I'm thinking of flash memory (memory card or internal).

Answer (score 0):

Remember that inputStream may not support resetting. Moreover, you have to call mark() first, to mark the point, inputStream should reset to. To check if mark/reset is supported, call InputStream.markSupported().

Without mark/reset you can just download the image to local file. It won't cause OutOfMemory and will allow you to decode the image from FileInputStream in the same way you tried to do it from web (with subsampling).